# Broke Headphone Jack ||| Merged With Speakers

Tags: audio, headphones, 3.5mm

I broke my headphone 3.5mm cable into my laptop, and after using glue and a cue tip, I was able to pull out the broken piece of headphone jack out. After that, I was no longer getting sound, so I did a system restore (Windows) to factory. Then, something strange started happening. I now am getting sound out of my speakers and my headphones, it shows that they are only 1 device. I have tried everything to fix it, but there seems to be no solution. It doesn't even seem to recognize my headphones, even though sound is coming out. Thanks!

Comment: How did you break the port? Sounds like there is a problem with the grounding of the port - you may have to re-solder it. What model do you have?

Comment: @ezra_vdj I hit the cable when the headphone jack was plugged in, and broke it off. I have the Lenovo y510p. How would I resolder it?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/1056641/sound-playing-through-speakers-when-headphones-are-plugged-in?rq=1 a similar question was asked here.  see Zoredache comment, as that is likely.

Answer (score 1):

There's two option you can go for:

1. The first would be to try and re-solder the jack by re-applying heat and letting the solder melt and form a new connection again. This option is more sketchy as you are using your own tools, and you are risking ruining your audio board altogether for a solution that might not even work.
2. LUCKY for you, the Lenovo y510p's audio board is a separate component - meaning that you can replace the thing altogether. I did some research and found in [this manual on page 86](http://www.manualslib.com/manual/580914/Lenovo-Ideapad-Y410p.html?page=90#manual) that the component number for the board is 90002737. I found ONE(!) person on eBay selling it that you can buy [new from here](http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/90002737-Lenovo-QIQY6-USB-Board-With-Cable-/162058582176?hash=item25bb71b8a0:g:UhsAAOSwrXdXKMpd). I would highly recommend spending the extra $$ and going with this solution as I'm sure this will fix your problem - and there's a plethora of tear-down guides on the internet to give you access to the board.

Hope this helps! Tell us how you end up doing.